# What is this parenthesis enclosed variable declaration syntax in Go?

Tags: variables, go, syntax, declaration

I am trying to find some information on parenthesis enclosed variable declaration syntax in Go but maybe I just do not know its name and that's why I cannot find it (just like with e.g. value and pointer receivers).

Namely I would like to know the rules behind this type of syntax:

```go
package main

import (
    "path"
)

// What's this syntax ? Is it exported ? 
var (
    rootDir = path.Join(home(), ".coolconfig")
)

func main() {
  // whatever
}
```

Are those variables in `var ()` block available in modules that import this one?

Comment: The syntax described here: https://tour.golang.org/basics/11

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I'm guessing that the downvote is because this is a very, very basic concept in go. It's introduced in the second page of the go tutorial - that's how basic it is: https://tour.golang.org/basics/2

Comment: I up voted it because reading through a tutorial may not be everyone's preferred method of learning. If you're experienced with other languages, its quite helpful to just go through the source of a library/framework and google for things you find different from your language of expertise.

Comment: FYI: the Tour calls it a "'factored' block", but the language spec doesn't even mention that much.

Comment: I also didn't pick up on the syntax when I ran through the tour. Page 11 was way too subtle for me (and/or I suppose I skim through text a little much) and page 2 is talking about imports -- which often have completely different syntax than variable declarations. I'm only here now because I'm trying to figure out what to call the syntax sugar now that I've seen it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This code

```
// What's this syntax ? Is it exported ? 
var (
    rootDir = path.Join(home(), ".coolconfig")
)
```

is just a longer way of writing

```
var rootDir = path.Join(home(), ".coolconfig")
```

However it is useful when declaring lots of vars at once.  Instead of

```
var one string
var two string
var three string
```

You can write

```
var (
    one string
    two string
    three string
)
```

The same trick works with `const` and `type` too.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `go fmt` does a pretty indenting for better readability with the `var(...)` syntax.

Comment: Why it does no need to add a semicolon like  rootDir := path.Join(home(), ".coolconfig") ?

Answer (score 10):

`var (...)` (and `const (...)` are just shorthand that let you avoid repeating the `var` keyword. It doesn't make a lot of sense with a single variable like this, but if you have multiple variables it can look nicer to group them this way.

It doesn't have anything to do with exporting. Variables declared in this way are exported (or not) based on the capitalization of their name, just like variables declared without the parentheses.